# Can't log in using IE10

Tags: support, login, internet-explorer

I'm clicking on the Yahoo logo and nothing happens. Why? Is there something I can do in order to avoid this kind of trouble?

Comment: Did you try other browsers? (Not having a Yahoo account, I can't try to reproduce this myself.)

Comment: Yes, I did it using Mozilla and this works well. But I like my IE10 and don't want to use a different browser only for log in to MSE.

Comment: Ok, that merits the [meta-tag:internet-explorer] tag.

Comment: I removed [meta-tag:discussion] (it doesn't work for you, there's not much to discuss); [meta-tag:bug] may be warranted, depending on your point of view.

Comment: @WillieWong It's ok. Btw, I'm clicking all four main logos and nothing happens.

Comment: @YACP: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170672/i-am-not-able-to-log-in-to-stack-exchange-using-ie10-under-windows-8 and see if any of the proposed work-around work for you. The developers are having a hard time reproducing this bug and it will help if you comment over there with more details about your set-up to help them isolate the problem.

Comment: If it helps, we've had issues with accessing our site using IE10, so this is not localized to MSE/MO.